# How to make a vector adjacency list graph of strings C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, adjacency-list

I've been struggling with these concepts for nearly a week now and keep getting nowhere! I understand how adjacency list graphs work on paper and can riddle off basic algorithms for everything I want to do... but I cant seem to code it in any usable form! My goal is to have an unweighted directed graph using adjacency lists that read in strings from a file and makes them into nodes. I want to use a vector to hold the nodes.

My original Idea was something along the lines of having (bad pseudo code):
*updated

```
Class of Graph
vector<string> list1
vector<string> list2

void addNode (string) //checks if node already exists in vector, if yes- do nothing, if no - add node to vector
//if <node> apears in <list1>
    //do nothing
//else
    //add <node> to list 1
    list1.pushback (string)

void addEdge (node_1, node_2)//connects nodes to form edge
    //point location of <string> in list1 to location in list2

void searchList //searches through list using DFS

void printGraph //prints graph using DFS

bool hasLink //checks to see if its linked
bool hasCycle //checks to see if
```

so far, this is the only actual code I have thats worked

```
 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc<2) {
        cout << "Filename not given." << endl;
        return 1;
}
ifstream infile;
infile.open(argv[1]);

int nodes = 0;
//int edges = 0;
istringstream Node_1;
istringstream Node_2;
char delimiter = ' ';
string line;
string token;
//want a loop that does all this while there's still an unread line
//current one won't terminate
while(infile){
    getline(infile, line); //reads in each line
    //check for spaces
    token = line.substr(0,line.find(delimiter));
    //node strings
    string node_1 = token.substr(0,token.find('-'));
    string node_2 = token.substr(token.find('-')+1,token.length());
    //cout << node_1 << endl << node_2 <<endl;
    nodes = nodes + 2;
    //edges++;

    //addNode(node_1);
    //addNode(node_2);
    //addEdge(node_1, node_2);
}
//printGraph
//hasCycle
//hasLink

//cout << "Read " << nodes << " cities and" << edges << " edges" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Example input:

Chicago,IL-Muncie,IN Chicago,IL-Fort_Wayne,IN

Cincinnati,OH-Fort_Wayne,IN Cincinnati,OH-Bloomington,IN

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: write out more details about what you know. draw out some examples with real data.

Comment: Whoops, the actual question is how to code adjacency lists

Comment: I know how to add items to a vector with `push_back`, I DONT know how to code that into pointing to another vector for the adjacency list

Comment: I updated my "bad pseudo code"

Comment: Can you show an example of input for your program?

Comment: edited original post to show that